# Adding a background that has no top on side margin in css

Tags: html, css, background-image

When adding my background image using CSS, I find that there appears to be a `margin` at the top and sides.

I tried adding `padding: 0; margin: 0;` and `left: 0px; top: 0px;` but this has not fixed the problem.

Here is my html

```css
#header {
  background: url(logo.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying width and height properties?

Comment: yes and this didn't work

Comment: Could you post a fiddle with your background image ?

Comment: tried the body margin reset but it didn't work

Comment: @Rebekah if you would like to keep the `<h1>` margins **so the title will not stick to the top of your page** but still want your background image to stick to the top of the page check my answer please (especially the last change which was crucial). It will help you do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` and headings (`<h1>` to `<h6>`) has default `margin` so you need to reset it

```css
body,
h1 {
  margin: 0
}
#header {
  background: url(//placehold.it/1600x900) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
  <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem could be that the body element has some margin or padding.

Try adding this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the image even display?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few built-in styles that every browser applies by default. One of these styles is a margin on the `body` element.

Try adding this:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: @Rebekah could you perhaps replicate the problem on jsfiddle and link it here for us?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the defaults of the browser by adding to your css these lines:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

**That cannot help alone in your case** because you need to also add:

```
#header {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

So the `<h1>` will not push his parent div down but will keep his margins like you want.